# Creating crontab via Capistrano instead of using crontab -e

Tags: ruby, capistrano, cron

I would like to include cron tasks in my Capistrano deployment files instead of using the following command to manually edit the crontab file:

```
crontab -e [username]
```

Is there a script I could use within the Capistrano run command to set the contents of the crontab?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On my linux box

```
crontab -u userName -l > fileName
```

lists the crontab file for userName in fileName.

Then I would use a ruby (or another language) script to update the file.

Finally I would use

```
crontab -u userName fileName
```

to update the crontab for userName

Comment: Thanks for posting this solution.  I think I will try this.

Answer (score 15):

Check out the [Whenever](http://github.com/javan/whenever) gem -- this may be stretching beyond what you're intending to do,  but it uses very simple (Ruby) syntax and makes it dead simple to setup cron jobs within a capistrano deployment script.

Comment: Thanks.  That is a neat looking gem.

Comment: It's fantastic -- I am using it in production on several app deployments.

Comment: After reading this answer I decided to try this for my own project.  Works great!  Ryan Bates put together a railscast episode on using Whenever:  http://railscasts.com/episodes/164-cron-in-ruby

Answer (score 4):

given that you have a variable set that is :`new_user`

and that you are using `use_sudo true`

```
desc "install crontab"
task :install_crontab do
  run "echo '0 23 * * * /home/#{new_user}/scripts/backup_#{new_user}.sh' | #{sudo} crontab -u #{new_user} -"
end
```

Answer (score 4):

```
def crontab_add(line)
  config = capture(%Q{crontab -l}).split "\n"
  return if config.include? line
  run %Q{(crontab -l; echo "#{line}") | crontab -}
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not include a crontab that can be installed to /etc/cron.d?